# WMS tile layer getfeatureinfo OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm using this link to try and add the WMS GetFeatureInfo Tile Layer functionality to my OpenLayers map

http://astuntechnology.github.io/osgis-ol3-leaflet/ol3/05-WMS-INFO.html

My code is currently as follows:

```
// Create a popup overlay which will be used to display feature info
var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
map.addOverlay(popup);

// Add an event handler for the map "singleclick" event
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {


    // Hide existing popup and reset it's offset
    popup.hide();
    popup.setOffset([0, 0]);

    // Attempt to find a marker from the planningAppsLayer
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });

    if (feature) {

        var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var props = feature.getProperties();
        var info = "<h2><a href='" + props.caseurl + "'>" + props.casereference + "</a></h2>";
            info += "<p>" + props.locationtext + "</p>";
            info += "<p>Status: " + props.status + " " + props.statusdesc + "</p>";
        // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
        popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
        popup.show(coord, info);

    } else {

        var url = lakes_wms.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                        evt.coordinate,
                        map.getView().getResolution(),
                        map.getView().getProjection(),
                        {
                            'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                            'propertyName': 'NAME,AREA_CODE,DESCRIPTIO'
                        }
                    );

        reqwest({
            url: url,
            type: 'json',
        }).then(function (data) {
            var feature = data.features[0];
            var props = feature.properties;
            var info = "<h2>" + props.NAME + "</h2><p>" + props.DESCRIPTIO + "</p>";
            popup.show(evt.coordinate, info);
        });

    }

});
```

However, I'm getting the error `expmap.js:565 Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined` I've tried going back on the linked example, but they don't seem to define it either. So I'm not sure what I'm defining it as in order to continue

Comment: Is `reqwest` in your code a typo or actually there?

Comment: No it's actually there as per the example in the link. I only changed the code to my layer name which I want the info to show for

Comment: It is a third-party library function, available from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reqwest@2.0.5/reqwest.min.js` or `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reqwest/2.0.5/reqwest.min.js`

Comment: @Mike Thanks! How do I incorporate this into my script so that it will enable the code to work?

Comment: You would add the link to the HMTL in the same way as the `ol.js` library link.

Comment: Thanks @Mike!! Next issue is now this error  `expmap.js:570 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
    at expmap.js:570
    at success (reqwest.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (reqwest.min.js:6).` It is referring to the `var props = feature.properties;` section of the code